# How to print PDF files from a specific directory in Uniface 10

Tags: uniface

I want to print PDF files that are in a specific directory such as C:\temp with Uniface 10. What would be the command and example code for this?

I can't find any examples of this in the Uniface 10 documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Uniface as an application has same limitations as any for PDF printing see

https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/Uniface/10/Search.htm?q=print%20pdf

Thus you have to consider do you use traditional print to Postscript driver and convert PS to PDF using Acrobat Distiller or GhostScript, both of which have an additional cost of licensed ownership. Also it's of limited value *"It is not possible to print Unicode to PostScript. Only selected European special characters are supported."* see https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/rocketd3/support/documentation/Uniface/10/uniface/platformSupport/printing/concepts/PostScriptSupport.htm?Highlight=print%20pdf

Or if using Windows you can use

> **Enhanced Printing**
> Enhanced printing uses native Windows features to print from Uniface applications on Windows. This makes it possible to print using proportional fonts, images, and layouts that better match what is displayed on the screen (widget-dependent printing).

Native Windows printing will require more work in defining system fonts and calling Microsoft Print Drivers to create PDF.

So "Uniface" on its own has very limited PDF methodologies. Thus I would NOT suggest you use it as a PDF to printer utility, there are many better third party applications specifically designed to Print PDF such as Acrobat Reader or MS Word/WordPad/Write Print to Printer (However WordPad/Write cannot handle PDF as input, only a Full copy of Office can).